# How can i find out if someone is using a sniffer on my network

Tags: sniffer

If I suspect someone is using a sniffer to gain access to my info how can I find out? Is it possible?

I need someone to explain this to me like im 5 because I know nothing about this stuff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect if someone is sniffing network packets on the LAN?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25011/how-can-i-detect-if-someone-is-sniffing-network-packets-on-the-lan), [How to find out that a NIC is in promiscuous mode on a LAN?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3630/how-to-find-out-that-a-nic-is-in-promiscuous-mode-on-a-lan)

Comment: If the linked answers do not explain things sufficiently, please explain the parts that you do not understand. Likely, the gap in understanding will be a basic networking concept and not a security concept.