# How can I detect mode interface of other machine is promiscuous

Tags: network, linux, malware, man-in-the-middle, python

I have a project that is to protect my box from attack man in the middle arp poison.
I should detect if interface mode of other machine is promiscuous.

I must write script python or command linux.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3630/13909)?

Answer (score 1):

The seminal work on detection of promiscuous interfaces on the network is [Detection of Promiscuous Modes using ARP Packets](http://www.securityfriday.com/promiscuous_detection_01.pdf):

> ...promiscuous mode detection is performed by checking the responses
>   of ARP packets, when ARP request packets are sent to all nodes on the
>   network

I don't know of implementations offhand, but the paper is detailed enough for you to write your own IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try **scapy**, if you're doing it on linux. It has great features for the case you need.

https://samsclass.info/124/proj11/proj16x-promscan.html