# Can the usage of Wireshark be detected when sniffing for packets in promiscuous mode?

Tags: ids, wireshark

I know that port scanning can set off IDS systems on certain networks due to the suspicious traffic it generates. Can the usage of Wireshark be detected on a network? If so, will using it set off any alert systems, and can it be traced back to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect it by passively listening on the network. But the switches will by default only relay broadcast traffic and traffic destined for a port to a port. One technique to overcome this is to [flood the switches with too many addresses](https://blog.rottenwifi.com/mac-flooding/), so that the tables overflow and the switch is forced to relay packets to all ports. This is however trivially detectable.

When it comes to active scanning, there may be [attacks that can distinguish hosts that have their NIC in promiscuous mode](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3630/how-to-find-out-that-a-nic-is-in-promiscuous-mode-on-a-lan).